# Unable to update previous messages after reconnection

Tags: c#, discord.net

I created a bot with a command, that allows the user to configure some sort of 'feed' to their channel.

This feed is supposed to send a message, save guild, channel and message id. And in a stand-alone update cycle, try to update the message with new information.

This all works fairly well, as long as it is within the same session.

Say the bot losses it's connection due to a discord outage, and re-connects x amount of time later, the bot no longer seems to be able to find, and thus update the message anymore.

In particular, it seems to be unable to retrieve the message by id
`var message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(playtimeFeed.MessageId) as SocketUserMessage;`

It's worth to note that I make use of `_settings` which is persisted in json format, and is loaded again upon bot reboot.

I also confirmed that the message still exists in the server at the channel, with the same message id. And that the bot has permissions to view the message history of the channel.

Thus my question, how come the `GetMessageAsync` is unable to retrieve a previously posted message after reconnecting?

Initialy invoked command

```
public async Task BindPlaytimeFeedAsync(ICommandContext context)
{
    var builder = await _scumService.GetTop25PlaytimeByDate(new DateTime(), DateTime.Now);

    var message = await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(null, false, builder.Build());
    _settings.PlaytimeFeed = new MessageInfo()
    {
        GuildId = context.Guild.Id,
        ChannelId = context.Channel.Id,
        MessageId = message.Id,
    };
    var ptFeedMessage = await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Playtime feed is now bound to this channel (this message self-destructs in 5 seconds)");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await ptFeedMessage.DeleteAsync();
}
```

The refresh interval of the feed is defined alongside the bot itself using a timer as seen below.

```
...
_client = new DiscordSocketClient(
    new DiscordSocketConfig
    {
        LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose,
        AlwaysDownloadUsers = true, // Start the cache off with updated information.
        MessageCacheSize = 1000
    }
);
_service = ConfigureServices();

_feedInterval = new Timer(async (e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("doing feed stuff");
    await HandleFeedsAsync();
}, null, 15000, 300000);
CmdHandler = new CommandHandler(_service, state);

...

private async Task HandleFeedsAsync()
{
    var botSettings = _service.GetService<ISettings>() as BotSettings;

    await HandleKdFeedAsync(botSettings.KdFeed);
    await HandlePlaytimeFeedAsync(botSettings.PlaytimeFeed);
    await HandleWeeklyPlaytimeFeed(botSettings.WeeklyPlaytimeFeed);
    await HandleAdminFeed(botSettings);
}
```

And ultimately the message is overwritten using the below snippet.

```
private async Task HandlePlaytimeFeedAsync(MessageInfo playtimeFeed)
{
    if (playtimeFeed == null)
        return;

    var scumService = _service.GetService<ScumService>();
    var guild = _client.GetGuild(playtimeFeed.GuildId);
    var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(playtimeFeed.ChannelId);
    var message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(playtimeFeed.MessageId) as SocketUserMessage;
    if (message == null)
        return;
    var builder = await scumService.GetTop25PlaytimeByDate(new DateTime(), DateTime.Now);

    await message.ModifyAsync(prop =>
    {
        prop.Embed = builder.Build();
    });
}
```

Comment: Most likely reason, the message is no longer in cache meaning it cannot be cast as a `SocketUserMessage`. So while it may be retrieved, your cast returns null. When the possibility exists that the message you are dealing with can be either a Socket entity or Rest entity, simply use the interface to interact with it -- `IUserMessage`

Comment: @Anu6is Would be a tad confusing, that the obtained object type switches after a reconnect. Non the less, using the interface would be a better idea overall. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In theory the object type can switch even without a disconnect. If cache fills up, your message can be ejected from cache and the next time it's retrieve it will be retrieved via a rest request. I believe if your session cannot be restored after a disconnect, the cache is cleared on reconnect.

Comment: @Anu6is That makes sense, tried it out, and it sure fixed the issue. Mind putting it as a answer so I can accept it ^^?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var message = await channel.GetMessageAsync(playtimeFeed.MessageId) as SocketUserMessage;`

The `GetMessageAsync` method attempts to retrieve a message from cache as a `SocketUserMessage`, if however the message is not found in cache, a rest request is performed which would return a `RestUserMessge`. By performing a soft cast on the result of `GetMessageAsync`, you can get null if/when a `RestUserMessage` is returned.

When the possibility exists that the message you are dealing with can be either a Socket entity or Rest entity, simply use the interface to interact with it -- `IUserMessage`.